# How to convert IAudioSessionControl to AudioSessionControl

Tags: c#, interface, naudio, audiosession

I am using NAudio wrapper and I am trying mute the session when it's created.

```
MMDevice _device = _deviceEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
_device.AudioSessionManager.OnSessionCreated += AudioSessionManager_OnSessionCreated;

private void AudioSessionManager_OnSessionCreated(object sender, IAudioSessionControl newSession)
{
        //mute session
}
```

in order to mute the  session,  I need to convert it from `IAudioSessionControl`  to `AudioSessionControl`

`IAudioSessionControl` is an interface and therefore I have no idea how to conver it.

A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you mean `NAudio.CoreAudioApi.AudioSessionControl` there is a [constructor](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/1943205525c1bd4c6dfd4dc20ff9756cbda08c31/NAudio/CoreAudioApi/AudioSessionControl.cs#L28) for it that takes an `IAudioSessionControl` as a parameter and encapsulates that interface.

```
private void AudioSessionManager_OnSessionCreated(object sender, IAudioSessionControl newSession)
{
    AudioSessionControl audioSession = new AudioSessionControl(newSession);
    // mute
    audioSession.SimpleAudioVolume.Mute = true;
}
```

The `AudioSessionControl` object wraps the `IAudioSessionControl` COM object and exposes additional functionality depending on the other interfaces available.  The more direct equivalent of this might be to use the [`ISimpleAudioVolume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316531.aspx) interface:

```
ISimpleAudioVolume simpleAudioVolume = newSession as ISimpleAudioVolume;
if (simpleAudioVolume != null)
    simpleAudioVolume.Mute = true;
```